# Racket: How do separate a string and save substrings in a vector

Tags: racket

I can split an input based on the whitespaces, but I need to save each of the generated substrings as elements of a vector so i can access each of them and check if the information in each is correct. I have this: 
    (define vec (vector))
    (vector-append (string-split input) vec)
    (display vec)

;(input is the name of my variable that a user enters in a text-field%)

But it gives me an error that says:
vector-append: contract violation
  expected: vector?
  given: '("fdsnmf" "ifnjin" "ifnuib")
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vector-append` is used to append two vectors, not a vector and a list.
To create the vector containing the list of input strings, you can do:

```
(define vec (apply vector (string-split input)))
```

For example,

```
(define input "this is random text")
(define vec (apply vector (string-split input)))

(display vec)
=> #(this is random text)
(vector-ref vec 2)
=> "random"
```

---

You can also use [`list->vector`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html?q=vector-put#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list-~3evector%29%29):

```
(define vec (list->vector (string-split input)))

(display vec)
=> #(this is random text)
```